# Access parent range values in nested range in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a helm chart where I try to generate a list of "targets", where each target has a different recipient but common config. This essentially means I have nested ranges, where the inner range needs to access values in the outer range. Unfortunately I've not been able to correctly pass values from the outer range to the inner range.

let's say I have the following value structure:

```yaml
emailReceivers:
- name: 'receiver 1'
  targets:
    - 'mail1@example.com'
    - 'mail2@example.com'
  text: exampletext 1
  sendResolved: true
- name: 'receiver 2'
  targets:
    - 'mail3@example.com'
    - 'mail4@example.com'
  text: exampletext 2
  sendResolved: false
```

and the following snippet from my template:

```golang
receivers:
{{- if .Values.emailReceivers }}
{{- with .Values.emailReceivers }}
{{- range . }}
- name: {{ .name }}
  emailConfigs:
  {{- range .targets }}
  - to: {{ . }}
    text: <needs to come from outer range>
    sendResolved: <needs to come from outer range>
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

I want to reach a state where I get the following output:

```yaml
receivers:
- name: 'receiver 1'
  emailConfigs:
  - to: 'mail1@example.com'
    text: 'exampletext 1'
    sendResolved: true
  - to: 'mail2@example.com'
    text: 'exampletext 1'
    sendResolved: true
- name: 'receiver 2'
  emailConfigs:
  - to: 'mail3@example.com'
    text: 'exampletext 2'
    sendResolved: false
  - to: 'mail4@example.com'
    text: 'exampletext 2'
    sendResolved: false
```

I can get the structure generated, but I can't figure out how to access the `text` and `sendResolved` value from the nested range or how to pass it into the range. I feel it's something trivial but so far no luck.. How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the current `range` item to a non-`.` variable.  The [Go text/template language](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) has specific syntax for this

```yaml
{{- range $receiver := . }}
- name: {{ .name }}
  emailConfigs:
  {{- range .targets }}
  - to: {{ . }}
    text: {{ $receiver.text }}
    sendResolved: {{ $receiver.sendResolved }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

So note the assignment `range $name := expression`, and inside the nested loop, the references to the outer `$receiver` variable.  The current `range` item is still assigned to `.` as well, so you could use either `.name` or `$receiver.name` when you're not in the nested loop.

Comment: Thank you. This works brilliantly! I was originally messing around with the named assignment but apparently on the wrong level. This instantly solved my problem!